# XML to object mapping using xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I want to map the following XML to the following java object. Probably i need to override the reflection function of stream. I tried the ReflectionConverter, but it didn't work for me. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
<Page>
  <Person name="client"/>
  <Person name="partner"/>
</Page>

Class Page{
  Person client;
  Person partner;
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to map this XML code to this Java code. Your XML will give a class Page whose attribute `List<Person> persons` contain Person object, whose attribute `name` is a String that contains the name of the Person.

Comment: If i have a list, then things would be a lot easier. I could add an implicit collection. The problem that, xstream maps the objects according to the field names and i have 2 objects of type person. The only way is to override the reflection method of xstream. I still don't know how to do that.